# Azure : enable programmatic deployment of market place images programatically

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

I was going through [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/working-with-marketplace-images-on-azure-resource-manager/) link to enable programmatic deployment of marketplace images.

It seems that it requires using the portal to enable programmatically deploying market place images. Would the same thing be possible using azure PowerShell or the rest API?

Comment: to deploy an azure marketplace image programmatically, the image should be enabled on the subscription. I am trying to enable it using PowerShell or the REST API.

Comment: well that is pretty obvious, which image exactly?

Comment: any marketplace image , that i create essentially.

Comment: Having the same issue myself, at the minute.

Just spent a little while updating our PowerShell provisioning scripts to cover a SendGrid template, only to hit this error:

`User failed validation to purchase resources. Error message: 'Legal terms have not been accepted for this item on this subscription. To accept legal terms, please go to the Azure portal (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=534873) and configure programmatic deployment for the Marketplace item or create it there for the first time'`

Answer (score 0):

You can accept marketplace terms with Powershell using [Set-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.marketplaceordering/Set-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms?view=azurermps-6.8.1#examples) :

```
Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Publisher "microsoft-ads" -Product "windows-data-science-vm" -Name "windows2016" | Set-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Accept
```